# How do you remove Disqus "comments" from Tumblr pages?

Tags: blog, tumblr, comments, disqus

How do you remove Disqus "comments" link from Tumblr pages?

I've managed to remove the Disqus comment box from all pages, so it only appears after posts. I used the following code:

```
{block:PermalinkPagination}
...disqus code...
{/block:PermalinkPagination}
```

But I still have the 'comments' link showing up on the pages. Does anyone know of a way to remove this from pages only?

For example, this is my "about" page:

http://www.kikou.co.uk/about

On the bottom right corner there's a clickable link for comments, I want to remove it, but still have it so the 'comments' link appears after Tumblr posts.

eg. the way it appears here: http://www.kikou.co.uk/

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 1):

I used the fact that the `{PostID}` variable is empty for static pages.

So declare a CSS class like this:

```
.hiddenOnStaticPages {
    display: none;
}
```

Then wrap the comments link (and the actual comments) in a `div` like this:

```
<div class="hiddenOnStaticPages{PostID}">
Comment HTML goes here...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the link in `{block:Date}...{/block:Date}` like this:

```
{block:Date}<a class="dsq-comment-count" href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread">Comments</a>{/block:Date}
```