# How do I remove the "Comments" word out of "x Comments" in Disqus Tumblr themes?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes, disqus

From [How do you remove Disqus "comments" from Tumblr pages?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/18885) and [Disqus: Setup instructions for Tumblr](https://disqus.com/admin/tumblr/), I found that you can show Disqus comments with

```
<a class="dsq-comment-count" href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread">Comments</a>
```

which seems to generate "x Comments" where x is the number of comments. Is there a way to get rid of the "Comments" bit, and just have the number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's managed in Disqus settings, not on Tumblr.

1. Log into your Disqus account
2. Go to the account that needs the change (the first page when logged in is the dashboard)
3. Click on `Settings` (the right-most tab)
4. Click on `Appearance`
5. Scroll down to the `Comment Count Link` group of settings (almost at the end of the page)
6. There you'll see three editable text fields labeled `Zero Comments`, `One Comment`, and `Multiple Comments`. Change the text in them to whatever you want.
7. Click the big blue button `Save Changes` at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 2):

Now that Disqus 2012 is out, if you want to change the text of your comment count, you have to temporarily disable Disqus 2012 to access the "Appearance" tab.